# Select a value from a table in current DB and use a variable in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA, I want to use values from a "Settings" table, instead of hard-coding folder locations etc. in the code. I can't figure out how to load a value from the table and use it in the code.

```
Dim oFSystem As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim sFolderPath As String



sFolderPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Main\Desktop\Files" 'BAD BAD, I WANT TO AVOID THIS
```

I have created a table "**Settings**", and I want to use the value

```
SELECT TOP 1 Settings.SettingsValue FROM Settings WHERE (((Settings.SettingName)="Files Folder Location"));
```

Comment: What's with TOP 1 ? How many records have SettingName="Files Folder Location" ?

Comment: If you have only one record that matches the criteria, Hans's method is better.

Comment: Heh, ya, I didn't even think of that. I just copy/pasted his query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim sFolderPath As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 SettingsValue FROM Settings WHERE SettingName="Files Folder Location")

If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs1.MoveFirst
    sFolderPath = rs1.Fields("SettingsValue")
End If
rs1.Close
set rs1 = Nothing
set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the DLookup function if you have only one record where SettingName="Files Folder Location".

```
sFolderPath = DLookup("SettingsValue", "Settings", "SettingName=""Files Folder Location""")
```

Comment: ...and if you don't have but one record, then your settings table is designed wrong.